# how to create local environment for openshift jboss with mysql application?

Tags: jboss, openshift

I tried to add JBoss 7.0 AS to eclipse and trying to deploy openshift project on it. but it fail. below is log

```
13:11:58,393 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (pool-1-thread-2) Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "panchali-1.0.war")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362) [jboss-dmr-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.requireChild(ObjectModelValue.java:298) [jboss-dmr-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:703) [jboss-dmr-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentDeployHandler.execute(DeploymentDeployHandler.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:83) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:350) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:119) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:154) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$100(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:114) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:112) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]

13:16:46,827 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (pool-1-thread-3) Operation ("undeploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "panchali-1.0.war")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362) [jboss-dmr-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:703) [jboss-dmr-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUndeployHandler.execute(DeploymentUndeployHandler.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:83) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:350) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:353) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:119) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:154) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$100(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:114) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:112) [jboss-as-controller-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_91]
```

I had created a simple application using openshift with two gear 1. JBoss 2. mysql

Now when i made changes in project i need to test that on PROD which is very dangerous. So i need to create similar dev env for testing and if success then we will push to PROD.

please provide detail steps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is also loading now. I Suppose to put path like "style/style.css".

I put path "/style/style.css" as "/" is taking as a root and searching for folder style. by removing "/" problem get solved.